# Learn asp.net mvc 3 from open source project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to learn ASP.NET MVC 3 (C#) by studying open source projects. Do you guys have any recommendations? I want to find a project that's written in MVC 3 from the ground up and uses all the latest technologies

Comment: [Getting Started with MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great start: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1

The Codeplex site for this is at http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

The downloads page also has a VB.net version of the code - http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/64379

Answer (score 10):

Here's a few open source ASP.NET MVC projects that might provide a helpful learning experience:

- [subtex](http://subtextproject.com/default.aspx)t ([source](http://code.google.com/p/subtext/source/checkout)):  a blog engine developed by [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/)
- [RaccoonBlog](https://github.com/fitzchak1/RaccoonBlog): a blog engine developed by Hibernating Rhinos(?) and used by [Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog)
- [TardisBank](https://github.com/mikehadlow/Suteki.TardisBank): online pocket money banking developed by [Mike Hadlow](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/)
- [FunnelWeb HQ](http://www.funnelweblog.com/) ([source](https://bitbucket.org/FunnelWeb/release/src)): another blog engine, developed by [Paul Stovell](http://www.paulstovell.com/)

Comment: i have downloaded subtext's source code and run it in vs. Can you refer to some documentation of subtext that can guide me through the source code?

Comment: i can't find any doc of  RaccoonBlog either.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any documentation on Subtext. You might want to consult the [project site](http://subtextproject.com/default.aspx) or Phil Haack's blog on the [subject](http://haacked.com/tags/Subtext/default.aspx).

Comment: I'm afraid there's even less documentation on RaccoonBlog. However, you might want to consult [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/blog/) on the [subject](http://ayende.com/blog/tags/blog).

Answer (score 2):

Start exploring any of these [ASP.NET MVC3 Open Source Applications](http://www.tampadev.org/News/Details/ASPNETMVCSampleApplicationsOpenSourceExamplesTutorials)

Answer (score 1):

This one includes MVC3, Unity, NuGet, EFCodeFirst, and MVC scaffolding:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Starter Site](http://mvc3starter.codeplex.com)

Enjoy !