# Is there a Asp.net Mvc sample application with N layers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for sample asp.net mvc application of medium size (preferably a blog engine) built using layered architecture and DI (preferably Ninject) so I can compare my coding practices with the sample application.

If there is some tutorial available with sample app, it will be like jam to the cake. If there is such open source project going on that I can join and work on it will be great too.

Comment: Take a look at these projects [Learn ASP.NET MVC 3 from Open Source Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159318/learn-asp-net-mvc-3-from-open-source-project/6160656#6160656)

Comment: thanks mrydengren. it is pretty useful link

Comment: [This link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/CRUD-Operations-Using-0aa46470) was in a deleted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the downloadble code for the great book Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework, at http://www.apress.com/9781430228868 .
It contains a full componentized MVC application using Ninject as a DI container. It's a lovely project to learn from, based on a great book I highly recommend.

Comment: thanks ofer it was great link +1. and mvc3 version of source code is also available at http://www.apress.com/9781430234043

Comment: Good to hear about the new book! Thanks.

Comment: u are welcome Ofer. a quick question where can i find sql scripts for sportsstore database?

Comment: Inside the source code, there is a folder called Chapters04to06. Inside it you'll find the sample project, and a file called PrepareDatabase.sql .

Answer (score 2):

I blogged about a blog engine here: http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/2/7/asp.net-mvc-3-razor-based-blog-engine-with-sql-ce-4.0
It is based on ASP.NET MVC 3 and SQL CE 4.0. Unity is used as DI container.

Comment: thanks daniel. i will sure check this out